# PyQt4 window not properly closing with signals and slots, only "x" button

Tags: window, pyqt, pyqt4

As the title suggests, when I create a push button, or a menu option for ending the program, the window doesn't close.

so I'm trying to figure out to end the program and close the window simultaneously. I've been using the tutorial:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/

which is great otherwise. So how do i connect the push button with ending & closing a widget?

Here is some sample code (copied from the tutorial) that I have been using. I cant seem to get the ending to copy exactly, but I don't think that's the issue anyways:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt4 tutorial 

This program creates a quit
button. When we press the button,
the application terminates. 

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: October 2011
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)       

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: `qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)` is the responsible line for connecting the buttons `cliked` signal to the applications `quit` slot. But pasting a working example probably isn't going to help you, you should post _your_ code that isn't working.

Comment: I copied the code from the tutorial exactly. So that code and mine are the same. Im not really versed enough in PyQt4 yet to make my own programs, I've just been using the tutorials.

Comment: Well, that code works...

Comment: I just tried this using PySide (Change "import PyQt4" to "import PySide" and it worked fine. It must be an environment issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code works. I have the same issue, but running it outside IDLE it works. No need to change  the code to call the quit method on the QtGui module.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is a QtGui.QApplication, so why are you connecting to the quit signal using QtCore.QCoreApplication? Changing that to `QtGui.QApplication.instance().quit` works.

Answer (score 0):

replace **qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)** with 
**qbtn.clicked.connect(self.close)**
I too faced the same problem (trying to learn Qt4 from the same zetcode tutorials) and came here to look for a solution