# PyQt4: Difference between QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit and self.close?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I've been doing a lot of research and have been unable to come up with anything describing this particular line of code in PyQt4. Like many others learning PyQt, I've been following zetcode's [PyQt4 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/). I'm still somewhat of a beginner in Python, but I'm doing my best to understand each line of code as I go through here, and one thing has me stumped:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)       

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I understand everything except this line:

```
qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
```

Can someone explain what exactly is going on here, specifically with `instance().quit`? I know that obviously it quits the program, I just don't understand what the code is actually doing and why. The only info I've been able to dig up on this is that instance() "returns a pointer to the application's QCoreApplication (or QApplication) instance", but this doesn't really help me understand (maybe I'm just not experienced enough, I don't know).

Additionally, is there a functional difference between the above line of code and this:

```
qbtn.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770703/pyqt4-window-not-properly-closing-with-signals-and-slots-only-x-button) which kind of touches on this whole topic, but the only response that mentions self.close as a possible alternative was downvoted with no explanation. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qbtn.clicked` is the signal emitted by the button.
`QCoreApplication.instance()` is the main application object. 
So it's connecting the button signal to the quit slot of the application.

In your second example the button will just close the window that owns the button. If the application has more than one window, or doesn't automatically quit on last window close, it will still be running.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a little...can you explain what the `.instance()` is actually doing and why it is needed? That's the part that's tripping me up.

Comment: Same purpose as the qApp global variable in C++ Qt. There should only be one instance of QApplication/QCoreApplication, so instance() will always return the same object. It's considered better programming style these days to use a function rather than a global variable.